# mobile mode i am not getting full width menu with close button

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Team,

I am working on responsive where I am getting menu in small size in the mobile mode but not as full width with close button.

Here is my image for the reference.

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/dqnhx3rj/4/)

[image]

Here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/GEPL-Capital-Logo.webp"></a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" style="margin-right:5px !important;" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse top_nav" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto ">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                    <hr class="hr_nav">
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link">Support</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item "><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar navbar-nav navbar-right" style="display:flex;">
                <li>
                    <button class="btn top_login">
                    Login
                </button>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <button class="btn sign_btn">
                    SignUp
                </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong. I am using [bootstrap](http://%3Clink%20href=%22https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%20integrity=%22sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC%22%20crossorigin=%22anonymous%22%3E) 5.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed

```
.top_nav {margin-left: 204px!important;}
```

and added

```
.top_nav {    
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    left: 0;
    padding-top: 70px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is the updated link [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/elvinmammadoff/8Lxku5v1/)

```
UPDATE jsfiddle
```

> [link](https://jsfiddle.net/elvinmammadoff/8Lxku5v1/16/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this is not one i am excepting 

When the user click the three icon menu user should view menu for the entire page 

with X icon in the top  to close the menu

Comment: ok, understood.

Comment: Check updated jsfiddle link, please